# Python function with a colon in the variable argument

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am reading the MITMProxy docs https://mitmproxy.org/#mitmdump and came across this Python example

```
from mitmproxy import http

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow):
    # redirect to different host
    if flow.request.pretty_host == "example.com":
        flow.request.host = "mitmproxy.org"
    # answer from proxy
    elif flow.request.path.endswith("/brew"):
        flow.response = http.HTTPResponse.make(
            418, b"I'm a teapot",
        )
```

I have never seen a colon in a function argument like that before. Can anyone explain what that is doing and how I can learn more about it?

Comment: This may help - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: These are "type hints".  They have no actual function in your program other than documentation and flags for code analyzers (and for programmers who use your code).

Comment: Appreciate the answers, mystery solved!

Answer (score 2):

A big thank you to @alani and @RufusVS who correctly pointed out these are type hints.

Something I had never come across and was able to read more about here https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484 and here https://realpython.com/lessons/pros-and-cons-type-hints/

Thanks again for the prompt responses!

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs, these are "Function Annotations," whose purpose is to serve as a type hint. Function annotations take the form `def foo(param: "function") -> "annotation":` where both `"function"` and `"annotation"` are any valid Python expression.